# Error while adding UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

So I am trying to display horizontally scrollable collection view inside tableviewcell. the code i am using is

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
UICollectionViewController *cv = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewID"];
cv.view.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
[self addChildViewController:cv];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cv.view];
[cv didMoveToParentViewController:self];  
return cell; 
}
```

I am getting error: Object can not be nil. I'd appreciate if someone can help me out understanding the error.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this in my app.

I found it much easier to subclass UITableViewCell.  The I could put all the UICollectionView setup and the UICollectionView datasource and delegate inside the code for the cell.

I then provided one public property of type NSArray which I pass into the cell.  The cell then uses this array as the datasource for the UICollectionView that it owns itself.

Made it a lot easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

check your UICollectionViewControlle's attribute inspector for identifier value {collectionViewID}

EDIT
[self addChildViewController:cv]; --> I think you want to add cv to the cell, isn't you?

Comment: then why self isn't you want [cell addChildViewController:cv];

Comment: I'm getting error "no visible @interface for UIView declares addchildviewcontrolelr..